# Grails SQLServerException Microsoft Database Incorrect syntax near 'limit'

Tags: sql-server, grails

I am working with a Microsoft Database in my Grails 3.1.1 project and right now I am just using scaffolding to manage the data. I am encountering the error `Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.` whenever I attempt to render the index page of a controller.
Here is the full error log:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: could not extract ResultSet; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [S0001]; error code [102]; Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.
    at inkinventory.IsInkInventoryController.index(IsInkInventoryController.groovy:13) ~[main/:na]
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96) ~[grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93) ~[grails-core-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53) ~[spring-security-core-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62) ~[spring-security-core-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58) ~[spring-security-core-3.0.3.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_73]
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216) ~[sqljdbc-4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515) ~[sqljdbc-4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404) ~[sqljdbc-4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350) ~[sqljdbc-4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696) ~[sqljdbc-4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715) ~[sqljdbc-4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180) ~[sqljdbc-4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155) ~[sqljdbc-4.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:285) ~[sqljdbc-4.jar:na]
    at grails.orm.PagedResultList.<init>(PagedResultList.java:43) ~[grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

And the line of code that it is pointing to as the error:

```
def index(Integer max) {
        params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
        respond IsInkInventory.list(params), model:[isInkInventoryCount: IsInkInventory.count()]
    }
```

And here is by database configuration:

```
dataSources:
    dataSource:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        username: sa
        password:
    sqlDB:
        pooled: true
        jmxExport: true
        driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        username: {un}
        password: {pw}
```

Comment: what the sql query look like?

Comment: It's not a query that I am running.  It's one that is behind the scenes in the gorm model that is pulling all of the data from the table into the index page of the controller, so I can't really tell you what the query looks like. I would imagine it's something close to a select all query.

Comment: As an addendum, I have connected an application to this specific database before with the exact same setup, which is why I'm confounded on how this is giving me issues now.

Comment: `Limit` is a `mysql` keyword, are you sure you're not mixing them up?

Comment: Then Grails might be doing something wrong behind the scenes. Like I said earlier, I myself have not created any queries. All that I have done is generated the views and controllers for the domain class.

Comment: Thats clear, that you are using the GORM to get the data, It might be SQL conflict between hibernate dialect and MS SQL format. So post the query generated by GORM

Comment: The query that is being generated that I assume is causing this issue is this `select this_.id as id1_0_0_, this_.barcode as barcode2_0_0_, this_.name as name3_0_0_, this_.quantity as quantity4_0_0_, this_.quillOrderNumber as quillOrd5_0_0_, this_.type as type6_0_0_ from is_ink_inventory this_ limit ?`

Comment: Is there a way to change the generated query to use top instead of limit?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the h2 database connection, which seems to have resolved the issue. I assume it wasn't certain how to generate the query because of the two different syntax between the two data connections

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the below plugin in `build.gradle`:

   ```
   compile group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc', version: '8.4.1.jre8'
   ```
2. In `application.yml` add `driverClassName` and `dialect` as shown below:

   ```
   dataSource:
       pooled: true
       jmxExport: true
       driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
       username: admin
       password: '123456'
       dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
   ```
3. Run the project and the error will be fixed.